# Why is state not working in handleScroll in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

For some reason, when I acces 'height' or 'scrollPos' in the 'handleScroll' function, they have their initial value. However, if I add a 'p' tag with '{height}', it is displayed correctly.

```
const [scrollPos, setScrollPos] = useState(0);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const [top, setTop] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(ref?.current?.clientHeight);
    setScrollPos(-window.pageYOffset);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const x = -window.pageYOffset;

    const dif = x - scrollPos;

    setTop(top + dif > 0 ? 0 : top + dif < -height ? -height : top + dif);
    setScrollPos(x);
  };
```

I am converting the component from a CC to a RFC, and it worked before.

Comment: Are `top` and `height` states being used in your returned JSX (do they influence your UI in some way), or are they being used for something else? Do they have to be state values or could they be refs?

Comment: Yes, they affect it and have to be state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the state of `handleScroll` never changes when it's triggered by the event. So the callback of the event needs to be recreated every time it is needed to have the current state updated inside the implementaiton of the callback.

Here's a solution:

In the dependency array of the `useEffect` creating the event, pass the state variables to be used. And, to avoid the event to be duplicated every time the `useEffect` callback is called, it needs to be removed. For this you can use the return callback of the function

Here what your new hooks will looks like with this solution:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(ref?.current?.clientHeight);
    setScrollPos(-window.pageYOffset);
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [height, scrollPos, top]);
```

That way, the event will be recreated everytime one of the three values is updated.

#### Update

As you commented, another way to do it is to pass directly the function `handleScroll` inside the dependencies array of the useEffect. But in that case I recommand you to use the `useCallback` hook that will recompute the function only if a value inside the dependencies array has changed (else it will be at each rerender of the component, and that happen a lot)

```
 const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    // ...
  }, [top, height, scrollPos]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [handleScroll]);
```

---

#### Why does this works ?

I think the best way to explain this is to see the differents states of a component as snapshot. Each time a value change, a new snapshot is created, rewritting the implementation of every function with the values of the states, rerendering the template etc...

So, everytime the state is updated, the implementation of the function of the component will be recomputed with the new values.
Meaning that if i have this state in a component:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

And a function like this:

```
function getCount(){
  return count; // Let's supposed that count is in th
}
```

Will actually be computed like this in the snapshot :

```
function getCount(){
  return 0;
}
```

So, when you pass the `handleScroll` function as a callback of `window.addEventListener`, you are actually passing a function computed with a specific value of the state of the component, so the callback will never be up to date.

That is way doing this method works, you are actually passing a different function everytime !

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! I've also seen after I posted the question that it works even if I add 'handleScroll' in the dependencies instead of 'height, scrollPos, top'. I don't understand how this works, could you please explain it if you know? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are right, but  doing so will actually need something else. I have updated my answer to add more explanations. Hope it helps !